# Add view on top of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

I would like a view on top of my uinavigationcontroller's top view but

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview: myView];
```

does not work.

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:myView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

[self.view addSubView:view];

Comment: unfortunately this view goes underneath the navigation bar

Comment: Are you looking to do a modal view? In that case you'll want the UINavigationController pushViewController method.

Comment: I m trying to add a view between the navigation controller's view and a modal that s smaller than the screen, in order to disable the user's interaction with the view underneath the modal

Comment: Perhaps set the userInteractionEnabled property of that view to false?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can set the navigation bar hidden, and extend edges to top and bottom of the screen